# Как можно получить процентное соотношение заполненности атрибута для каждого атрибута в таблице? ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

прошу знатоков помощи
Есть таблица в ней N-ное количество атрибутов (допустим 50), задача получить процентное соотношение (на крайний случай просто количество) незаполненности атрибутов ( то есть null-евых) во всей таблице. По итогу вид результата должен быть примерно такой:

| Наименование атрибута | Количество пустых значений |
| --- | --- |
| 1 атрибут | 67% (или например 20к записей) |
| 2 атрибут | 30% |
| ... | ... |
| N атрибут | N-ное процентное соотношение |

Comment: `100 * AVG(CASE WHEN column IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS column_percent`. Ну и UNPIVOT.

Comment: @Akina >100 * AVG(CASE WHEN column IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS column_percent вот эту часть понимаю, а unpivot как сработает сразу для всей таблицы? + условие в кейс конструкции же для одного поля только

Comment: А нельзя просто посчитать `COUNT(column)/COUNT() as column_percent`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Можно... но это лишние телодвижения.